# Can not ping internal systems while on VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

System A and B are Windows machines and on the same network, let's called it Net1. They can ping each other.

When System C (on a different network) connects to Net1 via VPN (Forticlient), it cannot ping system A or B.

I believe this may be a firewall issue. I disabled Windows defender on A but still no ping. Antivirus is ESET and there is a network firewall, but I am not sure how to turn on or off.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the people who maintain the Fortinet VPN. They probably disallowed split tunneling, which can cut off local LAN access by forcing all traffic through the tunnel. (Presuming that clients A and B are on a private network). Changing your windows firewall won't do anything about this; this restriction won't be anywhere that you're allowed to make changes in.

The VPN administrator will typically be following a policy that says to configure the VPN this way, but if you can make a good pitch, you might be able to get yours needs accommodated.

Comment: https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD48945 is the solution - allowing split tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 treats different LAN segments as outside networks (public as it calls them).

To fix this, you need to properly adjust your Firewall rules and allow what you need to work with "public" networks.

Many anti-viruses can control the Windows Firewall policies, so you may be able to create a proper policy like that also.